# Функция запускается только через onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему функция runCode() запускается только через button onclick? Пробовал разные варианты по этой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842590/run-function-when-page-is-loaded), все равно результат не изменился, на что я должен обратить внимание?

```js
var viewCollection = null;
function runCode() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
        var web = clientContext.get_web();

        var listCollection = web.get_lists();
        var list = listCollection.getByTitle("Tasks");
        this.viewCollection = list.get_views();

        var viewInfo = new SP.ViewCreationInformation();
        viewInfo.set_title('MyView');
        this.viewCollection.add(viewInfo);

        clientContext.load(this.viewCollection);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var viewInfo = 'Tasks list current views: \n\n';
    var viewEnumerator = this.viewCollection.getEnumerator();
    while (viewEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var view = viewEnumerator.get_current();
        viewInfo += view.get_title() + '\n';
    }
    alert(viewInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

```html
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Run Code" onclick="runCode()" />
```

Comment: _на что я должен обратить внимание?_ - на то, что ты нигде и не вызываешь эту функцию. Кроме того неясно что и как именно ты пробовал, и почему решил, что это не сработало

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за отзыв, пишу window.onload = runCode; и ничего ((

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov, забыл скобки поставить

Comment: @Yuri, Нет не забыл. здесь как раз не надо

Comment: Коллеги вот так работает: setTimeout(runCode, 1000);

Comment: _пишу window.onload = runCode;_ - где пишешь? сделай [mcve] где ключевое слово **минимальный**

Comment: Что консоль пишет?

Comment: window.onload = runCode; пишу уже в самом конце после function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }, вообще положение менял по-разному, никакого результата.

Comment: В консоли все чисто, ничего не срабатывает, никаких ошибок нет.

Comment: Что-то мне не нравится. Вы точно запускаете так? `function runCode() {...}; window.onload = runCode;`

Comment: абсолютно точно...

Comment: есть вероятность, что где-то на странице по умолчанию встроен синхронный запрос, платформа все же не новая с .net fr 3.5, может поэтому так происходит.

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov, по вашему коду я вижу, что вы не закрыли функцию `onQuerySucceeded()` и `while` в ней

Comment: Извиняюсь, это моя ошибка при вставке кода в редактор, поправил, но суть не изменилась...

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov, пока отсутствует [mcve] можно только пальцем в небо тыкать.

Comment: стандартный пример отработал без проблем: function doosomething()
  {
    alert('ok');
  } далее window.onload = doosomething; Проблема конкретно с моим кодом выше, ладно спасибо буду разбираться дальше...в принципе setTimeout() мне достаточно...большое вам спасибо за обратную связь.

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov, В твоем коде выше только одна проблема с функцией `runCode` - ты ее нигде не вызываешь.

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov скорее всего проблема заключается в том, что `JSOM` еще подгрузил компоненты SP. Отсюда `clientContext` у Вас скорее всего `undefined` или `null`, поэтому функция и не выполняется. Недаром в `JSOM` выполнение функций при/после загрузки оборачивают в `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', someFunction)` ожидая загрузки скрипта и вызова в `callback` функции `someFunction`. Попробуйте после получения `clientContext` добавить строку `console.log(clientContext);` для проверки значение `clientContext`.

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov попробуйте вот так `window.onload = function(){runCode()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, порядок выполнения скриптов нарушен. Проверьте в каком порядке загружаются скрипты. Когда Вы нажимаете на кнопку срабатывает событие onClick и как правило вся страница к этому времени загружена. Соответственно, где бы Вы не расположили кнопку, функция будет вызвана. Однако если обратить внимание на пример ниже, то `window.onload` не будет вызывать функцию, так как этой функции еще не существует. Есть еще вариант, что у Вас некоторые скрипты подключаются асинхронно. В этом и может лежать проблема.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button onClick="func('Кнопка выше скрипта');">Кнопка выше скрипта</button>

    <script>

    window.onload = func('Метод onload объекта window, ДО объявления функции');

    var func = function( message ){
        alert(message);
    };

    </script>

    <button onClick="func('Кнопка ниже скрипта');">Кнопка ниже скрипта</button>
</body>

</html>
```